# Efficient use of Core Image with AV Foundation

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, video-processing, core-image

I'm writing an iOS app that applies filters to existing video files and outputs the results to new ones. Initially, I tried using Brad Larson's nice framework, [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). Although I was able to output filtered video files without much effort, the output wasn't perfect: the videos were the proper length, but some frames were missing, and others were duplicated (see [Issue 1501](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1501) for more info). I plan to learn more about OpenGL ES so that I can better investigate the dropped/skipped frames issue. However, in the meantime, I'm exploring other options for rendering my video files.

I'm already familiar with Core Image, so I decided to leverage it in an alternative video-filtering solution. Within a block passed to `AVAssetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:usingBlock:`, I filter and output each frame of the input video file like so:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
{
    CMTime presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferRef inputPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage* frame = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:inputPixelBuffer];
    // a CIFilter created outside the "isReadyForMoreMediaData" loop
    [screenBlend setValue:frame forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CVPixelBufferRef outputPixelBuffer;
    CVReturn result = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool, &outputPixelBuffer);

    // verify that everything's gonna be ok
    NSAssert(result == kCVReturnSuccess, @"CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer failed with error code");
    NSAssert(CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(outputPixelBuffer) == kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, @"Wrong pixel format");

    [self.coreImageContext render:screenBlend.outputImage toCVPixelBuffer:outputPixelBuffer];
    BOOL success = [assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:outputPixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTimeStamp];
    CVPixelBufferRelease(outputPixelBuffer);
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = NULL;
    completedOrFailed = !success;
}
```

This works well: the rendering seems reasonably fast, and the resulting video file doesn't have any missing or duplicated frames. However, I'm not confident that my code is as efficient as it could be. Specifically, my questions are

1. Does this approach allow the device to keep all frame data on the GPU, or are there any methods (e.g. `imageWithCVPixelBuffer:` or `render:toCVPixelBuffer:`) that prematurely copy pixels to the CPU?
2. Would it be more efficient to use `CIContext`'s `drawImage:inRect:fromRect:` to draw to an OpenGLES context?
3. If the answer to #2 is yes, what's the proper way to pipe the results of `drawImage:inRect:fromRect:` into a `CVPixelBufferRef` so that it can be appended to the output video file?

I've searched for an example of how to use `CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect:` to render filtered video frames, but haven't found any. Notably, the source for `GPUImageMovieWriter` does something similar, but since a) I don't really understand it yet, and b) it's not working quite right for this use case, I'm wary of copying its solution.

Comment: If you could find answers to your questions, could you please share here?

Comment: @aligurbuz, I never found clear answers to these questions, but my original code has been running successfully for many years now, so I guess it's OK!